# check the checkbox is check or uncheck

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know if the user has checked the checkbox and if so, then it should disable the date; if unchecked, then enable the date. Change event is there on checkbox

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').click(function () {
        if ($('#chkShowAll').prop('checked')) {
            $("#MainContent_txtSrchFromDate").attr('readonly', 'readonly');
            $("#MainContent_txtSrchToDate").attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        }

        else {
            $("#MainContent_txtSrchFromDate").removeAttr('readonly', 'readonly');
            $("#MainContent_txtSrchToDate").removeAttr('readonly', 'readonly');
         }
    });
```

Comment: Please, clarify a bit more. What problem are you facing? read this link to save us and you some time: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your selector only adds the click event handler to checkboxes that are checked on page load. Also, you should be using `.prop('readonly', true | false)` to turn on readonly state.

Comment: `$('input[type=checkbox]:checked')` <-- why are you only binding it to a checked input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
  let dateElements = $("#MainContent_txtSrchFromDate, #MainContent_txtSrchToDate");
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    dateElements.prop("readonly", true);
  } else {
    dateElements.prop("readonly", false);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is short and simple.

```
 $('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
        $('#MainContent_txtSrchToDate').prop('disabled', $(this).is(":checked"));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

To check is a checkbox is checked or not, you can simply do it like this:

```
$('#chkShowAll').checked
```

It returns true if checked else it returns false

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#checkbox_id").is(':checked')){
 console.log("checked");
}
else{
  console.log("not checked");
}
```

**This show checkbox is checked or not**